# Firing bullets on a certain frame.

Tags: actionscript-3, frame

I could not find topic like this and that is why I am posting this question. I have a side scrolling game with the character set up in positions with frame labels- animation states to stand, jump, run, kneel and fire. She is also made to fire bullets with separate class file. The problem is that right now she is firing bullets in all of the animation states. The question is how do I make this character fire the bullets only on the frame label fire. The frame label fire consists of 2 frames and I want the launching of the bullet to happen on the second frame. Which means that the keyboard space will be pressed for a second or two before it goes to this frame and then it will fire (like in real life). 
I tried to connect the animation state to the bullets somehow and tried to put the condition in these lines of code somehow:

```
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
if (Animation state "Fire (2)")
fireBullet();
}
```

But it did not work, it doesn't know what I am talking about. The class file for the bullet is separate and I don't think is relevant to the problem. 
The rest of the timeline code is like this:

```
var bulletList:Array = new Array();

if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){

fireBullet();

}
}
function fireBullet():void
{
var playerDirection:String;
if(player.scaleX < 0){
playerDirection = "left";
} else if(player.scaleX > 0){
playerDirection = "right";
}
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.x - scrollX, player.y - scrollY, 
playerDirection xSpeed);
back.addChild(bullet);
```

Thank you. I hope that my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `addFrameScript`, AS3's mystery function that can be useful in this situation. And that would look something like this:

```
playerAnimation.addFrameScript( insertFrameNumber, fireBullet );
```

`addFrameScript` runs the method passed as a parameter when the `MovieClip` reaches a certain frame.

I believe how you would want to use this in your current code:

```
player.addFrameScript( 5, fireBullet );
```

Then in your `KEY_UP` handler:

```
function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{ 
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){ 
        spacePressed = false; 
        player.gotoAndPlay("fire");
    }
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){ 
        leftPressed = false; 
    } 
    else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){ 
        rightPressed = false;
    } 
    else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){ 
        upPressed = false; 
    } 
    else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){ 
        downPressed = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The key code is part of another function called key up handler, so I take it out and replace player animation with my character instance name "player"?

Comment: function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
 if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
  spacePressed = false;
 
 }if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
  leftPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
  rightPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
  upPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
  downPressed = false;
 }
 
 if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
  
  fireBullet();
  
  }

}

Comment: Do i make a variable for onKeyDown? Sorry for so many questions. Can I upload the file anywhere?

Comment: So the good thing about the `KEY_DOWN` event is that it will continue to fire while the key is being pressed. I think that is the desired effect you are looking for. So the answer is yes, make the `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown` and implement it with the example I provided. Currently your `keyUpHandler()` will only fire once, I don't think that is what you are looking for. Also yes take out the `playerAnimation` and replace it with your `player` instance if that is the correct asset.

Comment: Thank you That is the effect i want and just did that. Before the key up handler function I have the same key down function and I tried to put the code on that.

Comment: function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
 if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
  spacePressed = true;
 
 }if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
  leftPressed = true;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
  rightPressed = true;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
  upPressed = true;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
  downPressed = true;
  
  }
  if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
  if(player.currentFrameLabel == "fire (2)")
  fireBullet();
  }
  else {player.gotoAndPlay("fire");
  }
}

Comment: I don't think I have my player MC setup correctly, so it does not work and it messes up with the running animation. Is there a way for you to see it for one minute? Is uploading possible on this site? It's a problem I can't figure out for like 5 days already.

Comment: I can't take a look at it currently, but just as an observation you also left the if statement with the `fireBullet()` in your `keyUpHandler()`, you need to remove that. I'm suspect your movieclip is setup a certain way with timeline code that is throwing this off.

Comment: function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
 if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
  spacePressed = false;
 
 }if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
  leftPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
  rightPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
  upPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
  downPressed = false;
 }
}

Comment: I cleared it sorry! It does not fire the bullets at all right now. I think I have to put something on the key up handler

Comment: Try the `addFrameScript` way, there's a lot going on with your code and assets I can't see so that is a much simpler solution. Just replace the `insertFrameNumber` with the frame number of your player animation that has the label fire (2).

Comment: Where do I add the Frame script? do you know? Is that on the key down or key up handler?

Comment: It's in neither, either put it in a function before that or if you are doing it in the timeline you can do it outside of a function.

Comment: I removed the key code fire bullet from the function and entered in the timeline where the rest of the code is player.addFrameScript( 6, fireBullet ); Nothing happened.

Comment: Heh, so you have to do player.gotoAndPlay("fire"), then it should work :)

Comment: The fire (2) frame is inside the player's 6th frame label. Can you show me the whole code? So it's  player.addFrameScript( 6, fireBullet ) player.gotoAndPlay("fire") after it? Still nothing.

Comment: It just occurred to me your frame number in the `addFrameScript` could be wrong, try `player.addFrameScript(5, fireBullet);`

Comment: You are probably right I have a bullet class connected with the bullets, but the command should still work. Can you send me those test files at naumovich1@outlook.com? I will try to figure it out somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is a reaction at frame 5, she is firing like 4 bullets at tapping down the button like robocop, but that is still not the desired result.

Comment: Anyway, Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: You described the issue as only wanting the bullet to fire at the specified frame. Is that not what you wanted? I think your question may need rephrasing...

Comment: Ok I see now, I'll change around my answer using addFrameScript still and see if you get the desired effect.

Comment: Yes that's right. One bullet when she lifts the gun at pressing spacebar until it comes from the frame label fire to it's second frame and stop. Here it is in it's original form. https://app.box.com/files/0/f/0/1/f_13521222161 Sorry I did not think of that sooner.

Comment: I see that the objective is too difficult to achieve. I will mark the answer as correct anyway. Thanks.